# 'list' object is not callable, not a rename issue

Tags: python, list, callable

as the title say i have been searching the solution of this problem :

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

for a while, but i did find only answers about naming variables with defaults names like, for instance, list. And i think this is not my case, in particular this the concerned code:

```
next_matrix = 0
c = 0

routes = []
mapp_matrix = []
mapp = []

def del_nl(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        del l[i][-1]

# check if there is a valid route in a map from a starting point 
def route(n_map, n_command, s_point):
    for i in n_command:
        if i == 'N':
            s_point[0] = s_point[0] - 1
        elif i == 'S':
            s_point[0] = s_point[0] + 1
        elif i == 'E':
            s_point[1] = s_point[1] + 1
        elif i == 'W':
            s_point[1] = s_point[1] -1 

        try:
            if n_map[s_point[0]][s_point[1]] != '.':
                return False

        except IndexError:
                return False
return True



## Getting datas for every map ##
with open("/home/senso/programming/ctf_magio/input-sample.txt", "r") as  f:
   for line in f:
       # i am reading values for the dimension of the map 
       if c == next_matrix:
           line = line.split(" ")
           int_list = [int(i) for i in line]

           if not c == 0:
              del_nl(mapp)
              mapp_matrix.append(mapp[:])
              del mapp[:]


       # reading the commands     
       elif c == next_matrix + 1:
           route = list(line)
           del route[-1]
           routes.append(route)
           next_matrix = next_matrix + int_list[0] + 2
       else: 
           #building the map
           mapp.append(list(line))
       c = c+1

del_nl(mapp)
mapp_matrix.append(mapp[:])

ship_alive = 0
for i in range(len(mapp_matrix)):
    for j in range(len(mapp_matrix[i])):
        for z in range(len(mapp_matrix[i][j])):
            #oh my god is O(n^3), will it explode??
            if mapp_matrix[i][j][z] == '.':
                point = [j, z]

                if route(mapp_matrix[i], routes[i], point):
                      ship_alive = 1 + ship_alive
```

and i get this error

> File "capitanSonar.py", line 78, in 
>       if route(mapp_matrix[i], routes[i], point):
>   TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

If i try to call 'route' with static lists it works.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"I can post the whole code if needed."_ Yes please :-) There's nothing obviously wrong in the bits you've shared, so the whole thing should be helpful.

Comment: You're most likely reassigning `route` variable somewhere in the code you're didn't include

Comment: Yes @igonato you were right! I called a list 'route'  while reading the file.
So now i feel like i have to change the title ehe :). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
   # reading the commands     
   elif c == next_matrix + 1:
       route = list(line)  # <- Here. Pick a different name for the list
       del route[-1]
       routes.append(route)
       next_matrix = next_matrix + int_list[0] + 2
   else: 
       #building the map
       mapp.append(list(line))
   c = c+1
```